# With Python, I want to add the last two values of a string but I want to keep double digit numbers together and not include spaces in the string index

Tags: python, fibonacci, rosalind

I need to create a fibonacci sequence (k = 5, until 5 elements are in the sequence) from an original string containing two starting values. While calling the last two elements in the string forward (newnumber= old[-1] + old[-2]) I pull the number "5" and what seems to be a "black space". Is there a way to lift the integers in the original sequence above the type of black spaces to make it easier to manipulate the useful data I need?

Below is my code for reference.

ORIGINAL STRING IN FIRST FILE:

```
31 5
```

```
with open("C:\\Users\\dylan\\Downloads\\rosalind_fib.txt", "r") as old:
    old = old.read()
    ## An attempt to make the numbers the only elemenet, this did not work --> old = list(old)
new = open("C:\\Users\\dylan\\Downloads\\new.txt", "w")

## to test the values for each index --> print(old[###])

while len(old) < 6:
    newnumber= old[-1] + old[-2]
    old += newnumber
    if len(old) == 6:
        break
new.write(old)



new.close()
print(new)
```

The desired output is:

```
31 5 36 41 77
```

A sequence of 5 numbers where the sum of the last two numbers in the sequence is the new number added to the end of sequence.

Comment: Is the separator a space character or is it literally `''BLANK''`?

Comment: It is like ' ' .

Comment: Edited the question to clarify -- the way you posted it originally made it look like the "space" between the numbers was a bunch of stuff that isn't actually whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` to split the string on whitespace.  When you write it back out you can use `join()` to turn the list of numbers back into a string.

```
with open('old.txt') as f:
    nums = [int(n) for n in f.read().strip().split()]

while len(nums) < 5:
    nums.append(nums[-2] + nums[-1])

with open('new.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(' '.join(str(n) for n in nums))
```

Result:

```
>echo 31 5 > old.txt

>cat old.txt
31 5

>python test.py

>cat new.txt
31 5 36 41 77
```

Breaking down how we read the file a bit: the first thing we do is `read()` the file, giving us a string:

```
>>> with open ("old.txt") as f:
...     contents = f.read()
...
>>> contents
'31 5 \n'
```

We want to `strip` the contents to get rid of the trailing whitespace (otherwise when we `split` later we'll have an empty string at the end):

```
>>> contents.strip()
'31 5'
```

and then we `split()` that to produce a list:

```
>>> contents.strip().split()
['31', '5']
```

and we can iterate over that in a list comprehension to get a list of ints:

```
>>> [int(n) for n in contents.strip().split()]
[31, 5]
```

Comment: Great! For clarity, in line 2 " nums = [int(n) for n in f.read().strip().split()] " creates an array named nums by FIRST spliting file f at the "BLANK" elements, by default. This would create " '31','BLANK5BLANKBLANK' ". Then strips the "BLANK" elements from the none blank elements with the default operation of .strip(), creating " '31','5' ". Then this command finally reads each new manipulated element as an integer element of the new array: "nums".

Comment: Or is file f first read, stripped of "BLANK" elements, and finally split and combined along the stripped  "BLANK" elements to build the integer elements of the new array: "nums"? This process would look like READ: " '3''1''BLANK''5''BLANK''BLANK' "  --> STRIP: " '3''1''''5''''' " -->SPLIT:  " '31''5' ".

Comment: There is no string like `"BLANK"` anywhere in any of this.  It's just regular whitespace.

Comment: Perfect demonstration!